# What is a complex data type and an Imaginary data type in C++?

Tags: c++, types, complex-numbers

I know what imaginary and complex numbers are in the math world but what about in C++, what are data types of complex and imaginary. In addition, I see data types such as _Imaginary and _Complex. What is the difference and what are complex and imaginary data types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_Imaginary` and `_Complex` are keywords in the C99 language standard used for defining imaginary and complex floating-point variable types; they are not part of the C++ language.  They are not data types in and of themselves -- they modify the `float`, `double` and `long double` types.  For example:

```
float _Imaginary x;      // imaginary 32-bit number
double _Complex y;       // complex 64-bit number
long double _Complex z;  // complex 80-bit number
```

`_Imaginary` values are mostly equivalent to regular real values, except when you add a real with an imaginary value, you get a `_Complex` value.

The header file `<complex.h>` defines the macros `imaginary` as `_Imaginary` and `complex` as `_Complex`, as well as `I` as either `_Complex_I` or `_Imaginary_I` (the imaginary unit).  This is so that legacy C programs can use `complex` and `imaginary` as identifiers; new programs should use `complex` and `imaginary` instead of `_Complex` and `_Imaginary`.  Note that identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved by the implementation, so legacy code should never use `_Complex` or `_Imaginary`.

C++, on the other hand, does not use this, and instead has the templated types `std::complex<float>`, `std::complex<double>`, and `std::complex<long double>` for dealing with complex numbers.  Those classes function very similarly to the C99 types but are non-interchangeable.

Comment: Note, however, that C++11 specifies that `std::complex` shall have the same memory layout as C99 `_Complex`, with the explicit intent of preserving binary compatibility between C's `T _Complex` and C++'s `std::complex<T>` types.  Each type has two members, with the `real` one before the `imaginary` one, such that if cast into an array of type `T [2]`, `[0]` will be real and `[1]` will be imaginary.  See section "Non-static data members", [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Answer (score 4):

These are actually C datatypes, not C++ datatypes.

When creating new C standards, the committee avoids using new keywords. So, they use reserved identifiers, that begin with an underscore. Then, the standard may also provide a header file that defines a nicer macro (**complex**, instead of **_Complex**).

Since C++ is newer that C, it has included the **complex** datatype since it was first standardized, and doesn't need to resort to the underscored version.

Answer (score 0):

not [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/)?

and from [another source](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/e/index.php?title=Imaginary&oldid=160244):

```
_Imaginary
Revision as of 11:59, 3 December 2010 by PyBot (Talk | contribs)

Category

Reserved Words

Syntax

_Imaginary

Description

Reserved for future use.

    Warning: C++Builder does not implement _Imaginary but does treat it as a keyword when the -An compiler flag is set. Do not use _Imaginary as an identifier.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a header `<complex>` which defines a convenient complex number data type for you, all part of the standard library. Here is the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, there is a header called `<complex>` which defines a template class `double<>`, which can be instantiated for `float`, `double`, and `long double`. This allows you to define complex numbers and do the usual arithmetic operations and some functions.

There is no `imaginary` class or type in standard C++, just complex numbers with a real part of 0.0.  Any `imaginary` class would be some sort of vendor extension.  (Personally, I don't see that an `imaginary` class would be of much use.  It's not even closed under multiplication.)

Any name that begins with an underscore and is followed by a capital letter is specifically reserved for use by the implementation, and so there isn't anything standard C++ has to say about them.  Any such type would be implementation-specific, and you haven't specified an implementation.  Moreover, it's probably not something you should be using yourself.