# How to save rgb color to ppm file properly?

Tags: c, rgb, ppm

I try to make simple c program saving rgb color to ppm file usinf 1D array. It is educational project

```c
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h> //OpenM
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
fork of
mandelbrot-book how to write a book about the Mandelbrot set by Claude
Heiland-Alle https://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-book/blob/HEAD:/book/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77135883/why-do-my-functions-not-work-in-parallel


gcc c.c -lm -Wall -fopenmp

./a.out > rgb.ppm   // P6 = binary Portable PixMap see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#File_formats

convert rgb.ppm rgb.png
*/

double aspect_ratio = 16.0 / 9.0; // = w/h
const int h = 200;
int w; // = h * aspect_ratio;

const double r = 2.0; // plane radius
const double px = r / (h / 2);

double width;
double xMin;

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594913/getting-the-fractional-part-of-a-float-without-using-modf
double frac(double d) { return d - (int)d; }

// rgb in [0,1] range
void giveRGBColor(const complex double z, double *r, double *g, double *b) {

  *r = frac(abs((creal(z) - xMin)) / width); //
  *g = 1.0;
  *b = 1.0;
}

int main() {
  w = h * aspect_ratio; // The aspect ratio of an image is the ratio of its
                        // width to its height, and is expressed with two
                        // numbers separated by a colon, such as 16:9,
  unsigned char *img = malloc(3 * w * h); // image
  width = r * 2.0 * aspect_ratio;
  double height = r * 2.0;
  xMin = (0 + 0.5 - w / 2) / (h / 2) * r;

  fprintf(stderr, "image width = %.2f in world coordinate\n", width);
  fprintf(stderr, "image height = %.2f in world coordinate\n", height);
  fprintf(stderr, "image aspect ratio = width:height = %d:%d = %f = %f = %f\n",
          w, h, w / (1.0 * h), width / (1.0 * height), aspect_ratio);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
  for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
    double y = (h / 2 - (j + 0.5)) / (h / 2) * r;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
      double x = (i + 0.5 - w / 2) / (h / 2) * r; // for q=2 add -0.5
      double _Complex z = x + I * y;

      // color

      double red, grn, blu;

      giveRGBColor(z, &red, &grn, &blu); // compute rgb

      // convert to [0,255] integer and save rgb color to array
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 0] = (int)(255 * red);
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 1] = (int)(255 * grn);
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 2] = (int)(255 * blu);
    }
  }

  //
  printf("P6\n%d %d\n255\n", w, h);
  fwrite(img, 3 * w * h, 1, stdout);
  free(img);

  return 0;
}
```

Program works, but instead of simple monochrome **red** gradient I get **yellow** one.
[image]
What I do wrong?

Comment: In `giveRGBColor()` try `*r = 1; *g = *b = frac(abs((creal(z) - xMin)) / width);`

Comment: @pmg it gives red

Comment: Right! That's what I understood you wanted??? Anyway, search for color wheel/picker, play around with them, and make up your color pattern. For example: https://rgbcolorpicker.com/

Comment: If you want red output, why do you set green and blue with `*g = 1.0` and `*b = 1.0` rather than setting them to zero?

Comment: @MarkSetchell What is my problem/question !!!

Comment: I had to run the actual program to see my instinct that it results in a *cyan gradient*, hence downvoted as the question does not even have a proper [mre].

Comment: @ Antti Haapala -- Слава Україні So what is this program ? Have your read the question ?

Comment: See [netpbm ppm file format](https://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) for the file spec on how to save your data.

Comment: @Adam The program you've posted does _not_ generate the image you're showing; it generates one with a cyan-to-white gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my error. I wanted the monochrome 1d color gradient, but I have set the other color channels to 1 not to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Paring your program to the practical bare minimum and changing how `red` and `blu` are computed to show the effect you're after (well, a bit more too, with a black-to-blue gradient on the other axis):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  double aspect_ratio = 16.0 / 9.0;
  int h = 200;
  int w = h * aspect_ratio;
  unsigned char *img = malloc(3 * w * h); // image
  for (int j = 0; j < h; ++j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {
      double red = i / (double)w, grn = 0, blu = j / (double)h;

      // convert to [0,255] integer and save rgb color to array
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 0] = (int)(255 * red);
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 1] = (int)(255 * grn);
      img[3 * (j * w + i) + 2] = (int)(255 * blu);
    }
  }

  printf("P6\n%d %d\n255\n", w, h);
  fwrite(img, 3 * w * h, 1, stdout);
  free(img);

  return 0;
}
```

This yields this image:

[image]

In other words, we can tell your PPM writing code is absolutely fine.

Comment: Thx . Your program is shorter and works. Can you show me the error in my program ?